# How to multiply a vector with some specific columns in a DataFrame in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Here, I am working with LR model while doing predictive modeling. So, I get some parameters after the process, those needs to generate predicted values.
Say, I received parameter vector a=[a_0, a_1, a_2] if I use the only two-character variable to predict the best model, and have a data frame with more than three variables. Now, I want to multiply the vector 'a' with the corresponding column. 
 Excel formula would be like. 
      $A$2+J3*$A$3+L3*$A$4
or more general 
2+ 8.9*b+ 7*d= e

I tried to get the parameters into an array and then multiply it. But so far I can do if columns number is same as the length of an array. But I am not getting an idea, How to do for specific columns.
[Here df_1 is our actual dataFrame, and df_2 is our desired dataFrame. And a is our vector that we want to multiply it with df_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isDCj.png)

Comment: Your example is not clear, can you post the code snippet which you tried along with the example.

Answer (score 0):

its better to use numpy array for such operations. If somehow you already have dataframe then you can get numpy array it like below and perform the operations

```py
np_a = a.values
np_df1 = df_1[["b","d"]].values

df_2 = df_1.copy()
df_2["e"] = np.sum(np_a[1:]*np_df1, axis=1) + np_a[0]
```